# Array printing strange numbers

Tags: c, arrays

guys... I am kinda new in programming, so I would ask you this : I ´ve made program for user that would like to write down position of something. I assume , that this should be done using array. It looks like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
int positionA[1][1];

int i;
int j;
printf("Insert postitions x and y : \n");

for ( i=0;i<2;i--)
    {scanf("%d", &i);
    for ( j=0;j<2;j--)
            {
            scanf("%d", &j);
            }
    printf("%d", positionA[i][j]);
    }


return 0;
}
```

Please, dont be mad on me ,if I have this program made bad. 
Well and problem is, that I insert numbers like 2,5 . And at the output it appears like 1695956464 .

Sorry for bad English :P. And thanks for help !

Comment: It isn't clear what you want the program to do. Please give an example input and expected output.

Comment: Please, type in position of point A 
4 5
The position of point A is 4 5 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int positionA[1][1];
```

Declares a 1-by-1 array. That is, `positionA[0][0]` is its only element. You later address `positionA[1][1]`, which is outside its bounds. In C, an array with a size of, say, 10, allows indexes from 0 to 9 (that's 10 elements, starting with zero).

Also, NEVER mess with your loop variables inside the loop:

```
scanf("%d", &j);
```

assigns the input value to the variable `j`, which is your loop index, causing you to loop unknown number of times, and access the array *way* out of bounds.

Comment: It is impossible to know from the code whether they access `positionA[1][1]`.